# WPF, Create brush animation in Style.Triggers of a button style

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation, styles, storyboard

I am working now on a Button style, I've included a control template and style triggers. Now I want to make the background brush fade to a certain colour when mouse enter to button. But the colour animation won't work with a brush. and I'm stuck on that since yesterday. Here is what I've done so far in my button style:

```
<Converters:MathConverter x:Key="MathConverter" />
<Converters:ColorToBrushConverter x:Key="ColorToBrushConverter" />
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="FontSize"
            Value="{Binding FontSizeButton}" />
    <Setter Property="Margin"
            Value="{Binding FontSizeBase, Converter={StaticResource MathConverter}, ConverterParameter=@VALUE/3}" />
    <Setter Property="Padding"
            Value="{Binding FontSizeButton, Converter={StaticResource MathConverter}, ConverterParameter=@VALUE/3}" />
    <Setter Property="MinWidth"
            Value="{Binding ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
    <Setter Property="Width"
            Value="NaN" />
    <Setter Property="Background"
            Value="{Binding BrushBackButton}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
            Value="{Binding BrushBorder}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
            Value="{Binding BorderThicknessBase}" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border x:Name="MainBorder" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="Content"
                                      VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                      HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                      TextElement.Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <!--
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                 Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background"
                    Value="{Binding BrushBackButtonOver}" />
        </Trigger>
        -->
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard TargetProperty="Background">
                    <ColorAnimation To="Blue" Duration="10"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: The `Duration` property expects a `TimeSpan` object in this format: `0:0:10` for 10 seconds. Also, please see the [How to: Animate the Color or Opacity of a SolidColorBrush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753266(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN to find out how to do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the  [VisualStateManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.visualstatemanager%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for this kind of problem.

It may lead you to something like that :

```
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
     <Setter Property="Template">
       <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
           <Border x:Name ="Border" Background="LightBlue">
             <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                   <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                     <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.2"/>
                   </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                   <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                   <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                     <Storyboard>
                       <ColorAnimation 
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" 
                    To="Red"/>
                     </Storyboard>
                   </VisualState>
                   <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                      <Storyboard>
                         <ColorAnimation
                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" 
                   To="Blue"/>
                      </Storyboard>
                   </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
             </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
             <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
         </Border>
[...]
```

[Edit]
Concerning your specific problem, you should put your trigger in the ControlTemplate's Triggers.

```
 <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
 [...]
  <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
        <BeginStoryboard>
           <Storyboard  TargetName="Border" TargetProperty="(Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
               <ColorAnimation To="Blue" Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
           </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
      </EventTrigger>
   </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

Comment: Why should they use the `VisualStateManager` when it can be done much easier in a `Trigger`?

Comment: take a look at the link Sheridan provided in the comment of your question

Comment: @Sheridan VisualStateManager is more elegant powerful and flexible, and I don't find it particularly more difficult. Take a look at this article : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2009/02/27/the-visualstatemanager-and-triggers.aspx

Comment: Dude, I know about the `VisualStateManager`... of course its more powerful and in the right situation, it's great. My point is that for something as simple as this, it's overkill using that and being forced to write in the code behind (`GoToState`) when a simple `Trigger` could do the same thing. Still I agree to disagree and leave it there.

Comment: First, I'm not necessarily speaking to you, but also anyone that might be listening to our conversation. Still, I don't get your `GoToState` point. He's templating the standard button, which already "goes to state". No addition to code behind is needed here. @DavidDanielDiamond -> Updated my visual state manager solution to a functionnal one.